# How to structure the controller classes in a Java MVC web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, controller

I am working on a Java/Glassfish 4 MVC web application for a school project and I am not sure how to structure the contoller class.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
class User{
    private string userName;
    //the rest of the fields
    private Address address; //here is one problem, is this how i should do it or
    //or should i put the primary key of the address there.... How should i structure 
    // the constructor?????
}
```

My question is should i put the fields in the model class only or should i leave it here. Someone here suggested it is domain object and i wanted to know a general structure of a controller class.

Comment: Narrowed the question down!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is not a controller, its a domain object that is part of the model.

And the primary key of address, should indeed be a field within the Address class.

Comment: You mean I did it right? I wanted to know if i should just put the int there